# ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 and .NET ASPX application (not MVC)

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am looking to add SAML 2.0 SSO functionality into a legacy .NET Framework Win Forms (C#, 4.7.2) application. My application currently authenticates users via a username/password look-up from a SQL database.

I have downloaded and looked at the  ITfoxtec Identity Saml2 package but can't locate any documentation regarding using the package with a Framework web application (the notes relate to calling the package from within an MVC or MVC Core application).

Can someone point me towards any documentation or notes that may help me?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1):

The SAML 2.0 component is divided into the base library ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 and extension libraries ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Mvc and ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore for MVC and MVC core respectively.

The base library ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 do support .NET Framework 4.7.2. But I'm afraid there is currently no direct support for Win Forms in an extension library.

It is possible to implement the missing parts to support Win Forms, maybe by use of .ascx pages. If you choose to implement an extension which support Win Forms then please do share your code.